# variables do not change after exiting foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I am changing variable values ($eachRelationalColumn["columnFiler"]["enabled"], shows in the picture) in a foreach loop. The variables' value can be changed successfully within the foreach loop (See the second line and fourth line on the picture). however, once the variables leave the foreach loop, then the varibles become the original value which does not get changed (As highlighted in the picture, both enabled values remain true (1) instade of becoming asdsad or falsadsadasdse ).

[image: output]

```
   case "relationalColumnfilter":

          foreach ($_SESSION["config_arr"]['tableOptions']['relational_columns']['columns'] as $eachRelationalColumn) {

            if ($eachRelationalColumn["displayColumn"]) {

              if ($eachRelationalColumn["columnFiler"]["enabled"]) {
                
                //check if displayed relational option is in the selected column filter
                //if it is in the selected column filer then change the selected to true
                //if it is not in the selected column filter then change the selected to false
                if (in_array($eachRelationalColumn["columns_name"]["label"], $setting['value'])) {
                  echo "<br>" . $eachRelationalColumn["columns_name"]["label"] . " is selected " . "<br>";
                  $eachRelationalColumn["columnFiler"]["enabled"] = "asdsad";
                  echo $eachRelationalColumn["columnFiler"]["enabled"];
                } else {
                  echo "<br>" . $eachRelationalColumn["columns_name"]["label"] . " is unselected " . "<br>";
                  $eachRelationalColumn["columnFiler"]["enabled"] = "falsadsadasdse";
                  echo $eachRelationalColumn["columnFiler"]["enabled"];
                }


              }
              

            }

          }

          echo "<pre>";
          print_r($_SESSION["config_arr"]['tableOptions']['relational_columns']['columns']);
          echo "<pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks, DarkBee
but it seems like that question does not answer my question

Comment: How does it not help you? What did you try from the suggested answers? Please update your question with the attempts you've made

Comment: [demo with the suggested answer](https://ideone.com/JBanjt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for array values to change inside loop, you must add reference `&` to that item:

```php
foreach ($_SESSION["config_arr"]['tableOptions']['relational_columns']['columns'] as &$eachRelationalColumn) {
    $eachRelationalColumn = 'fooBar';
}
```